# Converting yyyy-mm-dd to integer representation in a database(Codefight Task)

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and have literately hit the rocks now on a codefight database [task](https://codefights.com/arcade/db/always-leave-table-in-order/aQJquGtwg4rgXwfqH/description). I would appreciate any help and a little bit of explanation.
**Here is the task(Clearer if you follow the link):**

Your nephews Huey, Dewey, and Louie are staying with you over the winter holidays. Ever since they arrived, you've hardly had a day go by without some kind of incident - the little rascals do whatever they please! Actually, you're not even mad; the ideas they come up with are pretty amazing, and it looks like there's even a system to their mischief.

You decided to track and analyze their behaviour, so you created the mischief table in your local database. The table has the following columns:

mischief_date: the date of the mischief (of the date type);
author: the nephew who caused the mischief ("Huey", "Dewey" or "Louie");
title: the title of the mischief.
It looks like each of your nephews is active on a specific day of the week. You decide to check your theory by creating another table as follows:
The resulting table should contain four columns, weekday, mischief_date, author, and title, where weekday is the weekday of mischief_date (0 for Monday, 1 for Tuesday, and so on, with 6 for Sunday). The table should be sorted by the weekday column, and for each weekday Huey's mischief should go first, Dewey's should go next, and Louie's should go last. In case of a tie, mischief_date should be a tie-breaker. If there's still a tie, the record with the lexicographically smallest title should go first.

It is guaranteed that all entries of mischief are unique.

Example

For the following table mischief

```
+---------------+--------+----------------------------------+
| mischief_date | author |              title               |
+---------------+--------+----------------------------------+
| 2016-12-01    | Dewey  | Cook the golden fish in a bucket |
| 2016-12-01    | Dewey  | Paint the walls pink             |
| 2016-12-01    | Huey   | Eat all the candies              |
| 2016-12-01    | Louie  | Wrap the cat in toilet paper     |
| 2016-12-08    | Louie  | Play hockey on linoleum          |
| 2017-01-01    | Huey   | Smash a window                   |
| 2017-02-06    | Dewey  | Create a rink on the porch       |
+---------------+--------+----------------------------------+
```

the output should be

```
+---------+---------------+--------+----------------------------------+
| weekday | mischief_date | author |              title               |
+---------+---------------+--------+----------------------------------+
|       0 | 2017-02-06    | Dewey  | Create a rink on the porch       |
|       3 | 2016-12-01    | Huey   | Eat all the candies              |
|       3 | 2016-12-01    | Dewey  | Cook the golden fish in a bucket |
|       3 | 2016-12-01    | Dewey  | Paint the walls pink             |
|       3 | 2016-12-01    | Louie  | Wrap the cat in toilet paper     |
|       3 | 2016-12-08    | Louie  | Play hockey on linoleum          |
|       6 | 2017-01-01    | Huey   | Smash a window                   |
+---------+---------------+--------+----------------------------------+
```

The first and the eighth of December are Thursdays, the sixth of February is a Monday, and the first of January is a Sunday.

The dates in the example are given in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

**Here is my code:**

```
/*Please add ; after each select statement*/

CREATE PROCEDURE mischievousNephews()


BEGIN
     DAYNAME(mischief_date) as weekday
     declare @iweekdayn INT
     select @iweekdayn = case weekday
     WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 6
     WHEN 'Monday' THEN 0
     WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 1
     WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 2
     WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 3
     WHEN 'Friday' THEN 4
     WHEN 'Saturday' THEN ;


     select @iweekdayn , mischief_date,author,title from mischief order by 
     wekdayn;


END
```

**And I have this result:**

mischief

```
+---------------+--------+----------------------------------+
| mischief_date | author |              title               |
+---------------+--------+----------------------------------+
| 2016-12-01    | Dewey  | Cook the golden fish in a bucket |
| 2016-12-01    | Dewey  | Paint the walls pink             |
| 2016-12-01    | Huey   | Eat all the candies              |
| 2016-12-01    | Louie  | Wrap the cat in toilet paper     |
| 2016-12-08    | Louie  | Play hockey on linoleum          |
| 2017-01-01    | Huey   | Smash a window                   |
| 2017-02-06    | Dewey  | Create a rink on the porch       |
+---------------+--------+----------------------------------+
```

Output:

```
+----------+---------------+--------+----------------------------------+
| weekday  | mischief_date | author |              title               |
+----------+---------------+--------+----------------------------------+
| Monday   | 2017-02-06    | Dewey  | Create a rink on the porch       |
| Sunday   | 2017-01-01    | Huey   | Smash a window                   |
| Thursday | 2016-12-01    | Dewey  | Cook the golden fish in a bucket |
| Thursday | 2016-12-01    | Dewey  | Paint the walls pink             |
| Thursday | 2016-12-01    | Huey   | Eat all the candies              |
| Thursday | 2016-12-01    | Louie  | Wrap the cat in toilet paper     |
| Thursday | 2016-12-08    | Louie  | Play hockey on linoleum          |
+----------+---------------+--------+----------------------------------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+---------+---------------+--------+----------------------------------+
| weekday | mischief_date | author |              title               |
+---------+---------------+--------+----------------------------------+
|       0 | 2017-02-06    | Dewey  | Create a rink on the porch       |
|       3 | 2016-12-01    | Huey   | Eat all the candies              |
|       3 | 2016-12-01    | Dewey  | Cook the golden fish in a bucket |
|       3 | 2016-12-01    | Dewey  | Paint the walls pink             |
|       3 | 2016-12-01    | Louie  | Wrap the cat in toilet paper     |
|       3 | 2016-12-08    | Louie  | Play hockey on linoleum          |
|       6 | 2017-01-01    | Huey   | Smash a window                   |
+---------+---------------+--------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Dear Donald, please read [ask] and edit your question. keep it short and well formatted. Thanks.

Comment: Look at `datename` function for the weekday name, and `datepart` for the numeric

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could simply use the WEEKDAY function, here is the documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee634550(v=sql.120).aspx

With return type = 3 it'll return the mondays has zero (0), tuesdays as 1 and so on...

After that all you need is a good old fashioned ORDER BY to have the order correct for the exercise:

```
ORDER BY weekday,mischief_date,title
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the function WEEKDAY(date), in MySQL doesn't need to be specified the return_type, it will return the weekday from Monday to Sunday starting by 0.
Also, in the ORDER BY check the function FIELD(column, 'Value_1', 'Value_2', ..., 'Value_x') for the specific order of the nephews name.
Don't forget the rest of the tie-breakers or your answer will be incomplete.
Good luck duck!

Answer (score 0):

The following query working fine. I have tried with the CodeSignal already!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mischievousNephews()
BEGIN
    SELECT WEEKDAY(mischief_date) AS weekday,mischief_date,author,title
    FROM mischief ORDER BY weekday, FIELD(author,"Huey","Dewey","Louie"),mischief_date,title;
END
```

Hope! it helps you! Thank you!